# How to fetch an artifact from artifactory repository using own domain name?

Tags: artifactory

Reaching artifacts stored in Artifactory requires some redundancy in the URL [1].
I would like to fetch artifacts using own domain [2].

Is:

```
https://my-domain.com/artifactory/my-project/an-artifact
```

Wish to be:

```
https://my-project.my-domain.com/an-artifact
```

---

### Remarks

[1] A few consequences of this:

- `artifactory/` in URL is revealing what tools are used at the backend, which may (in some contexts) be considered a security breach.
- Requires more to type.
- Makes it harder to exchange artifactory by some other solution in the future (AKA vendor lock-in).

[2] Similarly it is done with AWS S3 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you can do with any proxy, such as Nginx or Apache, and have your own domain to redirect to the /artifactory prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IT support in my company is saying this is not supported by the vendor, and "will break api functionality", thus wanted to see some real working examples from the folks. I've already seen some tutorials on Artifactory pages, but those are mostly for Docker and people in my support are not competent to map this to other use cases...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that rule like the following one would do the job:

```
rewrite ^/(?!artifactory) /artifactory/$repo/$request_uri;
```

Add it after other rewrite rules in Nginx reverse proxy configuration generated by Artifactory.